# Toast-like clickable alternative to launch intent for a NO-GUI app?

Tags: android

For the life of me I cannot figure this out. What I set about doing was have a clickable Toast message that would launch an intent. After googling I found out that toasts cannot be clickable. I thought I could use a PopupWindow to achieve the same, but my problem is my application has no View, and PopupWindows need root views.

```
public class MyApp extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Call an Android api method here

    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", 3000);
    finish();
    }
}
```

The app just calls an Android api and then shows a Toast. There is no GUI at all. 
So my question is, what can I replace this toast with so that I can have a clickable, dialog/popupwindow that will launch an Intent?

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for Android [Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Like @ρяσѕρєя K mentioned, you can use a `postDelayed` callback to cancel a dialog box after a specified time without the user intervening too.

Another way to do this would be with a Toast and a custom view.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setView(layout);
```

If you run into any problems because of not calling `setContentView` first, you can call it with a blank layout. And in your manifest set your Activity's theme as `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`.

This will essentially create a transparent activity. So it appears your dialog is on the previous activity the user was on

Comment: But then how can I make them disappear automatically like Toast message do?

Comment: you can add your own custom view to a toast message then.

Comment: *how can I make them disappear automatically like Toast message do?* you can do this using handler.postdelayed to cancel Dialogs after some time

Comment: I already tried custom views inside a toast message but they don't work as Toast messages do not handle click events.
@ρяσѕρєяK Can Dialogs be shown in Android even though my app does not have the setContentView call?

Comment: @AhmedAeonAxan I tried it using the custom view and toast way as you showed and it displays fine, but the problem is I want it to be clickable which still doesn't work with Toasts. Even if I have OnTouchListener attached to the custom view inside the Toast, it never gets called.

Comment: yes. toasts are not meant to be interactive. Use Dialogs if you want user interaction.